# Auto-reload TWO pages alternatingly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, reload

How to implement the following in JavaScript or so?

```
 - Wait 120 seconds
 - Open http://192.168.1.1/internet-disconnect (in an iframe or so, doesn't matter)
 - Wait 3 seconds
 - Open http://192.168.1.1/internet-connect
 - Repeat
```

Here's how I was trying:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="http://heise.de"></iframe>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe#iframe_id').attr('src', 'http://192.168.1.1/internet-disconnect');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('iframe#iframe_id').attr('src', 'http://192.168.1.1/internet-connect');
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

But it's messy and doesn't work the way it should.

Thanks!

Comment: in what way does this not work the way you want? also its 6 lines of code, how unmessy do you want it? how about load both iframes together and show/hide them?

Comment: Re: *doesn't work the way it should.*; so what's the problem you have? Every script "works as it should", since those are the commands you've given the computer. That they are something else from *what you intended* is a different matter, of course :-) You should describe what behaviour you're getting, and how this differs from what you *expect*, as this is not always easy for everyone to tell.

Comment: The *idea* sounds messy, it also sounds like an x-y problem. Perhaps you should explain *why* you want to do this

Comment: The "wrong" script works only once. At the 2nd repetition, it doesn't load the 2nd page anymore. I want to load both pages alternatingly in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval() instead if setTimeout()

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   var flag = 0;
   $(document).ready(function() {

       setInterval(function(){ 
           if(flag == 0){
               $('iframe#iframe_id').attr('src', 'http://192.168.1.1/internet-disconnect');
               flag=1;
           }else{
               $('iframe#iframe_id').attr('src', 'http://192.168.1.1/internet-connect');
               flag=0;
           }
       }, 3000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens, the original iframe contents remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var url1 = 'http://192.168.1.1/internet-disconnect';
    var url2 = 'http://192.168.1.1/internet-connect';
    var delay1 = 120000;
    var delay2 = 3000;
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);


    setInterval(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){iframe.src= url1;},delay1);
        setTimeout(function(){iframe.src= url2;},delay2);
    },delay1+delay2)
}
```